Recommended way of power switching external modules & peripherals
I recently designed a PCB that is battery powered. Ideally I want this to be a low powered device, and as such have endeavoured to implement controls and systems to decrease power consumption.
My MCU controls an array of power switches which are connected to modules, sensors and peripherals, for example a GPS. The power switch turns on and off the 3.3V supply. However when the switch is off, I find the module still has a voltage on it's pins ~2.3V or so, as if its still 'on'.
I am under the assumption, when the module has its power cut it is now drawing power from the GPIOs or through pull up resistors configured to set pin states - so essentially now my power switching is made redundant.
What I would like to know is how is what is the common practice in managing power switching to external modules/peripherals/systems - do I need a switch on every pin on that device to ensure I prevent it drawing power from its logic level pins. Do I know till pill my output GPIOs on my MCU low and place a diode on the GPIO input pins of the MCU to prevent power being drawn out?
Any recommendations would be useful!
Just to clarify, I have noticed this power draw on my SD card, my GPS module and another sensor when the power switch is off (and I know its definitely off).

Yeah, you have to disconnect (or set to zero) all pins on the device, not just depower it (cut VCC).
If it's a single point-to-point connection / bus, that's fine, add the enable/disable GPIO calls around the transaction functions and there you go.
If it's on a bus with other things, SPI or I2C for example, you need something else.  Maybe tristate gate(s), maybe an analog switch.
Mind that you must wait long enough for the device to power on, before communicating with it.  If it's a basic logic device, this may be trivial, but many devices have state machines or MCUs built in, and can take 100s of µs or more before they're ready.
This may be a good opportunity to check what kind of power management functions are available in your devices, or competing devices.  An idle / sleep / low-power / power-down state activated by command rather than hard switching, can be faster to recover from, and much less complicated in the PCB design.  The downside, some devices power down or "sleep" at merely µA, and others properly shut off in the nA.  Always read datasheets carefully.
